# Anope Services NickServ will not set modes on Identify

Tags: service, irc

I have set up Anope Services with IRCd-Hybrid. Everything works great, except for one thing... Registered and identified users don't receive a "+r" mode set. I only receive "Password accepted - you are now recognized.", and no second line showing what modes have been set, because it isn't even attempting to do so.

In my "services.conf", it is showing that "nickserv.example.conf" is being loaded, and changes made to this file are indeed reflected when the services are executed, except for the two related to the subject at hand:

```
    /*
 * If set, Services will set the channel modes a user has access to upon identifying, assuming
 * they are not already set.
 *
 * This directive is optional.
 */
modeonid = yes

/*
 * If set, Services will set these user modes on any user who identifies.
 *
 * This directive is optional.
 */
modesonid = "+r"
```

Am I missing something? I've clearly set these settings to be enabled, and in order to create channels that only registered users can access, I require this function, but it refuses to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had forgotten to set within IRCD-Hybrid's config that Anope is a service (Putting the service name within the "service" tag), silly mistake on my part!